# Doctrine one to one relationship, main table with two columns related to one table twice

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have two tables

sales_order

| order_id | shipping_address | billing_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc1 | 1 | 2 |
| zyx2 | 3 | 4 |
| qwe3 | 5 | 6 |

address

| id (auto increment) | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | city 1 | country 1 |
| 2 | city 2 | country 2 |
| 3 | city 3 | country 3 |
| 4 | city 4 | country 4 |
| 5 | city 5 | country 5 |
| 6 | city 6 | country 6 |

What I need to do with **Doctrine annotations** is read the records from the database.

```
class SalesOrder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="id")
     */
    private $shippingLine;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="id")
     */
    private $billingLine;

    public function getShippingLine()
    {
        return $this->shippingLine;
    }

    public function getBillingLine()
    {
        return $this->billingLine;
    }
}
```

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SalesOrder", inversedBy="shippingLine")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SalesOrder", inversedBy="billingLine")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;
}
```

When I run this bit of code

```
$orderDetails = $em->getRepository(SalesOrder::class)->find('abc1');
```

The results are

```
{
    "salesOrderId":"abc1",
    "shippingAddress":1,
    "billingAddress":2,
    "shippingLine":null,
    "billingLine":null,
}
```

I know that its possible using raw sql

```
SELECT
    sales_order_id, shipping_address, billing_address, a1.*, a2.*
FROM
    sales_order
JOIN
    address AS a1 ON a1.id = shipping_address
JOIN
    address as a2 ON a2.id = billing_address
WHERE
    order_id = 'abc1'
```

#### Question

How can I accomplish the raw sql version using Doctrine entities and annotations? Is it even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Your association mapping is wrong, the definition on `Address::$id` should be on `Address::$order` Your current mapping implies that the billing and shipping addresses are the same and are identical to the `SalesOrder::$orderId`. You are probably wanting a `ManyToOne(targetEntity="SalesOrder")` association on `Address::$order` and `ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")` association on `SalesOrder::$shippingLine` and `SalesOrder::$billingLine` eg: `Address->getSalesOrder()`, `SalesOrder->getBillingLine()` and `SalesOrder->getShippingLine()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to implement your solution but I still got `null` responses. I also played around with the lazy/eager fetch settings but that didn't help either.

I've convinced the TL to not go with this approach instead.

Comment: Be sure to clear your cache and ensure `ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")` definition is correct and is not `mappedBy=...`. As they are both uni-directional associations. where both the order table and address tables reference the other FKs. My Order addresses are mapped similarly, but with a discriminator mapping on a separate column that determines billing/destination address types. If your address table does not reference the `sales_order.order_id` FK, you would leave out `Address::$order` and the association.